# Find service owner of a kubernetes endpoints

Tags: kubernetes, kube-apiserver

I have an `endpoints` that I can see via (for example) :

```
kubectl get endpoints busybox-service
```

This endpoints is "backed" by a `service`:

```
kubectl get services busybox-service
```

Is there a way for me via the `endpoints` object, to find the "backing" service, without finding it by name?

What I mean by that, is having just the information from (for example):

```
kubectl get endpoints busybox-service -o=json
```

or anything like that, to be able to tell what the `metadata.uid` of the *service* is?

So, if I do : `kubectl get endpoints busybox-service -o=json`, I would get:

```
"metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "endpoints.kubernetes.io/last-change-trigger-time": "2023-03-19T19:40:08Z"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2023-03-19T19:40:08Z",
        "labels": {
            "a": "b"
        },
        "name": "busybox-service",
        "namespace": "default",
        "resourceVersion": "277476",
        "uid": "8d76841b-ad74-4697-8d47-e7449b2cea24"
    }
```

that is, I get the `uid` of the `endpoints`: `"uid": "8d76841b-ad74-4697-8d47-e7449b2cea24"`. Is there an extended call of some kind to the endpoints that would give me the `uid` of the service that this endpoints is based on.

Something like this does not exist, but may be there is a certain call that I miss:

```
"metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "endpoints.kubernetes.io/last-change-trigger-time": "2023-03-19T19:40:08Z"
        },
        "creationTimestamp": "2023-03-19T19:40:08Z",
        "labels": {
            "a": "b"
        },
        "name": "busybox-service",
        "namespace": "default",
        "resourceVersion": "277476",
        "uid": "8d76841b-ad74-4697-8d47-e7449b2cea24"
        "ownerReference": "<UID_OF_THE_SERVICE>"
    }
```

Notice the last field: `"ownerReference": "<UID_OF_THE_SERVICE>"` - in reality it does not exist, but may be I miss some kind of a call that would give me this information.

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately in [official k8](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/owners-dependents) documentation they only mention that [EndpointSlice](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/endpoint-slices/#ownership) has **ownerReference** but not the [Endpoints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/service-resources/endpoints-v1/).

Comment: @DharaniDharGolladasari yeah, `EndpointSlices` would have solved this for me, as they have support for both `ownerReferences` and `endpointslice.kubernetes.io/managed-by` and `kubernetes.io/service-name` which the controller would inject. If you want you can answer this question in this manner and I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Endpointslice** object may suit this kind of requirement as it has the **`ownerRefernce`** metadata and also the annotations like `kubernetes.io/servie-name` and `endpointslice.kubernetes.io/managed-by` which helps to get the source metadata.

1. `kubernetes.io/servie-name helps to indicate the name of the
   service object from which the Endpointslice is created.
2. `endpointslice.kubernetes.io/managed-by`
   which can be used to indicate controller or operator which is
   managing the `Endpointslice` object.

You can use kubectl describe command to get the details of **ownerReferences** and **annotations** as shown here

**ownerReferences:**

```
$ kubectl get endpointslice <endpointslice-name> -o=jsonpath='{.metadata.ownerReferences}'
```

**Annotations:**

```
 $ kubectl describe enpointslice <endpointslice-name> | grep kubernetes.io/servie-name

 $ kubectl describe enpointslice <endpointslice-name> | grep endpointslice.kubernetes.io/managed-by
```

For more detailed information refer to these documents [Endpointslice](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/endpoint-slices/#management), [Ownerships](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/owners-dependents/)